# Thread not synchronized with single lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I cannot properly synchronize this program, the result should be 0 in the second  println too, because the two threads create and pop 10000 times each.
Do i have to synchronize in a different way ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main00 {

Queue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
Random rand = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main00().doStuff();
}

public void doStuff(){
    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)produce();
        }
    });
    Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)consume();
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Starting threads, q size is : "+q.size());
    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    try{
        t1.join();
        t1.join();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){}

    System.out.println("Ending threads, q size is : "+q.size());
}

synchronized public void produce() {
    q.add(rand.nextInt(100));
}

synchronized public void consume() {
    q.poll();
}

}
```

Comment: Also, you can use the main thread to play the role of the consumer or producer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not joining the second thread:

```
    t1.join();
    t1.join();
```

Should be:

```
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
```

You're also using [`poll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll%28%29) which doesn't block:

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, or returns null if this queue is empty.

You may want to use [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html):

> Multiple threads should not access a PriorityQueue instance concurrently if any of the threads modifies the queue. Instead, use the thread-safe PriorityBlockingQueue class.

You can utilize the [`take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) method to avoid [busy-wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting):

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

Comment: `take` blocks indefinitely, which may or may not fit the use case (here, as there are exactly the same number of `produce` and `consume` invocations, it will work), but in general, you may often want to set a timeout instead.

Comment: @RemigiusStalder I'm assuming that is exactly the case: "the result should be 0 in the second println too, because the two threads create and pop 10000 times each". I did link the implementation just in case.

Answer (score 3):

A call to `poll` does not necessarily consume an element. If there is no element in the queue, it just returns null.

To make sure you effectively consume an element, you would write:

```
  while(q.poll() == null);
```

Moreover, the class `PriorityQueue` is not threadsafe according to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html. You shoule use the thread-safe `PriorityBlockingQueue` class, which has a `poll`method that blocks with a timeout.

Comment: Even though this is a valid solution, busy-waiting is generally a bad practice.

Comment: I just wanted to illustrate that one should check the result of the `poll` (hence "would" instead of "should"). Interestingly, the are various discussions on lock free concurrency. Using a non threadsafe queue is paramount in this situation.